# Eslint: can't override env after updating

Tags: javascript, eslint

I updated Eslint to the latest version, but I get `error  'path' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S path' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies`. I already have `env: { node: true }`. I tried removing `extends: ['airbnb']` and the error no longer appears. This suggests that the `env` field isn't being overridden.

Why can't I override the `env` field?

Edit: looks like it works if I remove `'import/resolver': 'webpack'`, but I need that line for other stuff to work. It used to work before updating, no idea what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly stumbled upon this answer:

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1396#issuecomment-509384041

Adding `"node": {}` fixes it for me.

```
"import/resolver": {
  "node": {},
  "webpack": {
    "config": "config/webpack/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```